# Book a Taxi using OLA API

Tags: android

I want to use following OLA APis,

- **Products**: Checks availability of taxis from pick up address
- **Products**: Checks ride estimate from pick up address to drop off address
- **bookings/create**: To book a Taxi

First two of them requires X-App Token, which I implemented successfully, but Booking a taxi requires X-App Token and authorization both. I got X-App Token while registering app. but unable to get authorization.
I suppose we can get authorization token after login. But no API available for login. So could anyone please tell, where we can get authorization token.

It may be possible we can get authorization token from "http://api.ola.gemius.com/auth/login", but it says "Wrong email or password", while I am already registered on OLA.

Comment: I am facing authentication issue while integrating the fare calculator. I am also not able to find the documentation. Can you please guide me. It is really urgent.

Comment: @Aarti verma have u got any solution..? If yes, plz let me know, I'm facing exactly same issue..

Answer (score 1):

After registration of your APP, you will get below details

1. X-APP-TOKEN
2. OAuth URL
3. Redirect URI

If you run above OAuth URL, it will ask to login/register. After successful login, it will ask to accept/deny, click on accept then it will redirect to "Redirect URI" with the access_token value. check the below sample code.

localhost/ola/getdetails.php#access_token=1b0f48c26ee149cda389319106b17078&state=state123&scope=profile%20booking&token_type=bearer&expires_in=15551999

**Note: access_token is the one which you want substitute against authorization**

Answer (score -1):

There are login apis-
Check the below link-

http://api.ola.gemius.com/doc/#authorization-login

http://developers.olacabs.com/api/3

You can also have a look at the following resources-

http://blog.attify.com/2015/02/01/ola-cabs-privacy-security-issue-discovered-appwatch/

https://medium.com/@CodeTheDevil/busting-ola-wallet-1ceea6174b1f

Comment: I am using "http://be.ola.gemius.com/api/auth/login" with parameters "country_code","email","password" for login from doc of "http://api.ola.gemius.com/doc/#authorization-login" and credentials are same which i use to login in OLA andorid aap,and response is "Wrong email or password".But if i use "http://be.ola.gemius.com/api/user" from same doc ,to register a new user,it takes "token" as parameter,where i can get this token.?

Comment: any suggesstion please

Comment: This is not the API for olacabs. The original link - http://developers.olacabs.com/